# PDO Select Statement always returns bool(true)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

In my php application I need to check if a category exists in the database. All categories are stored in the CATEGORII table and have a different ID stored. I have this code:

```
public static function cat_exists($cat_id){
global $db;
$query=$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM CATEGORII WHERE ID = :D");
$q=$query->execute(["D"=>$cat_id]);
}
```

$db comes from another file:

```
$host="localhost";
$db="...";
$user="...";
$pass="...";
$charset="utf8mb4";
$dsn="mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt=[
PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=>PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE=>PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES=>true,
];
$db=new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

If I var_dump() the result of the query, it returns bool(true) no matter what i pass as the function argument. Any help?

Comment: You don't fetch the result. You only execute the query. You want to look at methods like `fetch()` and `fetchAll()`. `$q` will only contain a boolean, true if the query has been executed successfully, false if there was an error.

Comment: If i use fetch(), fetchAll() or fetchColumn() it says that the member function fetch() was used on a boolean and gives a fatal error.

Comment: Because you are using wrong variables. As I can see, you are using my tutorial for connecting to database. Just be consistent and follow the tutorial again. It is shown there how to fetch a row. Or you can use a dedicated example, [SELECT query with named placeholders](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/select#prepare_named)